# Remove all instances of a charater from beginning and end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replaceall

Im trying to find a solution to remove all instances of a given character from the beginning and end of a string.

**Example:**

```
// Trim all double quotes (") from beginnning and end of string

let string = '""and then she said "hello, world" and walked away""';

string = string.trimAll('"',string); 

console.log(string); // and then she said "hello, world" and walked away
```

This function would effectively be to `trim` what `replaceAll` is to `replace`.

My replaceAll solutions is as follows:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

This would of course replace all instances of a character in the string, as opposed to just form both ends.

What Regex would be best in this instance?

Comment: Keep in mind that mutating the built-in objects is *very* bad practice - call a function instead.

Answer (score 3):

One option uses `replace`:

```js
var string = '""and then she said "hello, world" and walked away""';
string = string.replace(/"*(.*[^"])"*$/, "$1");
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I this case you can use:

```
string  = string.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
```

If you want to remove (trim) all such characters (linke ") use:

```
string = string.replace(/^["]+|["]+$/g, '');
```

In this way you can also define rtrim (right trim) or ltrim:

```
// ltirm
string = string.replace(/^"/, '');

// rtirm
string = string.replace(/"$/, '');
```

I hope these help you.

Comment: You probably want `string.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, '')`, but this is a good answer.